# Why Elements Change Size when I resize the navigator window?

Tags: html, css

I have this navbar:

[image: Web Withhout Navigator Resizing]

When I resize the page, this happens to the navbar:

[image: Navigator Resized]

How can I keep the elements on the left of the navbar visable?

The code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="mainMenu" class="width100 height10 blackBackgroundColor whiteFont">
            <img src="img/logoTest.png" />

            <ul style="background-color: red;" class="height100 width75 inlineblock allinlineblock">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**
At the end of the code, It's the menu configuration. When I say menu, it's the bar that is showed in the pictures.

```
    *{
    /*Configuration to delete default styles*/
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    color:black;

    list-style: none;
    font-style: none;
    border-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;

    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}



/*Configurations of common use*/

.width100{
    width: 100%;
}

.width75{
    width: 75%;
}

.width50{
    width: 50%;
}

.width25{
    width: 25%;
}

.height100{
    height: 100%;
}

.height75{
    height: 75%;
}

.height50{
    height: 50%;
}

.height25{
    height: 25%;
}

.height10{
    height: 10%;
}



.inlineblock{
    display: inline-block;
}

.allinlineblock *{
    display: inline-block;
}
/*
LIST OF COLOR USED:
With your text editor change the value here and then will change in all the document

Black 1: #212121
White 1: #f4f6f7
*/

.blackBackgroundColor{
    background-color: #212121;
}

.whiteBackgroundColor{
    background-color: #f4f6f7;
}

.blackFont{
    color: #212121;
}

.whiteFont{
    color: #f4f6f7;
}

#mainMenu{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

#mainMenu img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    height: 100%;
}

#mainMenu ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: You're asking why the size of the element changes when the window size changes? What did you think the percentage lengths you were giving were percentages of?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this use relative value for your ul!
it might work
i am still new to this!

```
* {
  /*Configuration to delete default styles*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;

  list-style: none;
  font-style: none;
  border-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;

  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

/*Configurations of common use*/

.width100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.width75 {
  width: 75%;
}

.width50 {
  width: 50%;
}

.width25 {
  width: 25%;
}

.height100 {
  height: 100%;
}

.height75 {
  height: 75%;
}

.height50 {
  height: 50%;
}

.height25 {
  height: 25%;
}

.height10 {
  height: 10%;
}

.inlineblock {
  display: inline-block;
}

.allinlineblock * {
  display: inline-block;
}
/*
LIST OF COLOR USED:
With your text editor change the value here and then will change in all the document

Black 1: #212121
White 1: #f4f6f7
*/

.blackBackgroundColor {
  background-color: #212121;
}

.whiteBackgroundColor {
  background-color: #f4f6f7;
}

.blackFont {
 color: #212121;
}

.whiteFont {
  color: #f4f6f7;
}

#mainMenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

#mainMenu img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#mainMenu ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10em;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give the elements a set width in pixels, if you use percentages they're going to shrink when the page does.

also, look into media queries, you can have dynamic css if the page goes below a certain size. (this would be real handy on mobile for example)